# issue with loading view controller

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have two view controller's first which show's gird of button's and second the detailed view
when clicking on any button for first View Controller i am loading detailed view controller.

```
   secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [secondViewController setFrame:CGRectMake(300, 60, 430, 620)];
    [self.view addSubview:secondViewController.view];
```

which need to appear on first view controller and setting frame and adding to second view controller.

When i load[add] my second view controller to the first.  Its allow me tap on other button's too i need to restrict on taping on any button when its loaded second view controller.

Comment: when you add the second viewController the first one is still visible?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha it need to visible! i need to had some kind of has on that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When second view controller added as subview then make all as many buttons u have make userInteractionEnabled to NO which u think not to be taped:

```
 yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

When remove second view controller don't forgot to userInteractionEnabled to YES which were made NO:

```
 yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: its working fine!  the same issue i am getting on gestures!  now i create grid of view on tap on any grid view i have same issue can you advice me how to fix it!

Comment: which issue do u have description ?

Answer (score 1):

add a overlay on first view and on it add the second view then your buttons will not be accessible.refer